# Using internal GPS of laptop/mobile in node applications

Tags: android, node.js, gps

I have been going through [this](https://github.com/infusion/GPS.js) node tutorial regarding GPS usage for real-time data gathering. In this example it uses an external GPS device to get the data and display on dashboard screen.

```
//file path: GPS.js/examples/dashboard/server.js
const file = '/dev/tty.usbmodem1421';
```

is there a way to use my mobile phone or laptops integrated GPS instead of external device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get GPS data from Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501719/how-to-get-gps-data-from-android-phone)

Comment: @MorrisonChang somehow it relates to my question but not exactly

Comment: Then you should clarify what is lacking in the suggestion, as you would configure Android to send out GPS NMEA data strings and read them in through a serial port opened by Node.js. You may also want to clarify on what OS the node server is running on as you mentioned laptops.

Comment: actually in suggested post it ask to get data through wired medium, I want to get data directly as my device (laptop) is same machine where I am coding, I want to use that GPS to get data is in tutorial mentioned in the question.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned what OS your laptop is running - Windows or Linux or even model of laptop w/GPS chip? That information is necessary for researching how to get GPS data from the laptop. And you should mention what research did you find. Otherwise use Android to USB serial to laptop running node.js.

Comment: its Windows. Hp Envy-360 convertible

Comment: I cannot see any *port* category in Device Manger.

Comment: From: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Unable-to-connect-usb-gps-receiver/td-p/7154875 not all HP Envy x360 have GPS, but if you do see this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-win_maps/windows-10-maps-with-usb-gps/8f615318-2736-4caa-a01d-e068a57f7b85?page=7 and check [Powershell: Getting GPS Coordinates in Windows 10 - Using Windows Location API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46287792/295004)